# How to get prices from products from array list of ids Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to sum up the product prices in order to calculate the total price to charge in Stripe.

I have a model `Campaign` that `has_many` `Products`.

I need to iterate the `campaign.selectedproducts` which is an array in order to get all of the product prices inside it.

**Campaign table column**

```
t.text "selectedproducts", default: [], array: true
```

**The selectedproducts column is an array of numbers corresponding to the product ids.**

```
    2.7.2 :001 > c = Campaign.last
    2.7.2 :011 > p = c.selectedproducts
    => ["7", "8"]
```

How can I get the `product.price` from each ID and sum them up?

Is it using `.map / .sum?`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`where`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-where) to find the selected products and call [`sum`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-sum) on the relation to compute the sum of the product prices (I'm assuming you're storing the cents in the `price` column).

```
campaign.products.where(id: campaign.selectedproducts).sum(:price)
```